# Same aspect ratio of progressbar in custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I have a listview with a custom row layout. In this custom row is a progressbar ( "circle" ) which indicates a loading state. To make the layout looks how i like it, im using layout_weight for the progressbar and the layout containing some other gui stuff.

Example:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

I want the progressbar to have the same aspect ratio.

My problem is that the progressbar looks weird on different devices. On my galaxy nexus everything looks fine and the progressbar has the same aspect ratio. But on - for example - my emulator, the progressbar looks like an egg and thats terrible.

Can someone please point out my error?

**Edit:**

I dont use wrap_content because the layout will use the progressbar's width for the rest of the view, which is really tiny ( then there is no place for the text ).

**Edit2:**

Two pictures showing the problem:

The "egg"
http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/2955/89xvdhrz_png.htm

Usage of the wrap_content
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/2955/sryrhkkk_png.htm

**Edit3:**

CFlex' approach. Whole xml-file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/text2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why don't u use wrap content instead of giving match_parent and 0dip in progressbar

Comment: edited my question. cant use wrap_content because my layout will be destroyed.

Comment: you can set style to progressbar like small ,normal & large. e.g. style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"

Comment: Thanks, i tried that. There is no "progressBarStyleNormal" resource. With small, the height is used for the whole row layout ( see picture two ) and it is too small. With large it also looks awful. Maybe my approach for this layout is completely wrong?

Comment: What if you use a LinearLayout in place of the progress bar - with the required dimensions - and then place the progress bar with `wrap_content` inside that layout?  I think it should do the trick: the explicit dimensions of the layout will ensure that the rest of your layout is not cut off, and `wrap_content` on the progress bar will ensure that it's not distorted.

Comment: Thanks Aleks G. But it wont solve my problem. With this approach it looks this way: http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/2955/ongxwqcn_png.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

Assuming you are in a horizontal `LinearLayout`

Tell me if this does not work.

**EDIT**: with a relativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @eftokay83 Indeed, that is weird. Can you post your entire xml ?

Comment: @eftokay83 did you try with android:layout_width="match_parent" for your horizontal linearLayout ?

Comment: yep, the result is the same if i set it for the second layout. If i set it for the progressbar the result was that the progressbar grabs ALL available space. Then nothing except the progressbar is on screen :) oh, i think it is dirty that i mix fill_parent and match_parent, but its the same.

Comment: @eftokay83 I edited my code with a relativeLayout. Tell me if it's ok

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you!! But still not perfect - do you have an idea how i can stretch the progressbar with same aspect ratio? But thanks a bunch @CFlex!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the circle doesn't keep the proportions with fill_parent and wrap_content.